# R - Zip path is too long

Tags: r, windows, sharepoint

When loading a file from a synced sharepoint folder - i am getting an error advising zip path is too long.

```
>test = read_excel(file_list[1])

Error: Evaluation error: cannot open the connection.
In addition: Warning message:
In unz(zip_path, file_path, open = "rb") : zip path is too long
```

I thought this may of been due to the character limitation within windows.

```
> nchar(file_list[1])
[1] 240
```

I have checked the registry, and LongPathsEnabled is set to 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps `withr::with_dir(dirname(file_list[1]), read_excel(basename(file_list[1])))`?

Comment: @r2evans Thanks, but i get the same error.

Comment: Interesting development: i swapped package to openxlsx::read.xlsx, which works, but readxl::read_excel does not.

Comment: What do you have in `file_list[1]` ?

Comment: I have been struggling with this for ages. From this link, I understand that you need to enable the registry, as you've done AND the program needs to be "Long Paths Aware". I'm not sure how to check if R is. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd